# How to detect in JS that PHP has performed a refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have form with class `popup-form`. On submit I send `formData` to my CI controller and then catch the response. If there are any validation errors they are displayed in same pop up div.

```
$('body').on('submit', '.popup-form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var formData = $(this).serialize(); 
        var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action');
        var linkId = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post(actionUrl, formData, function(response){ 
            $('#popup-div').html(response);
        });
    });
```

When I use this method on login I have a problem. Validation does not run, but an error is displayed, which is good. But if validation runs the program stores the user ID in a session (logged in) and need to refresh.

```
redirect('home', 'refesh');
```

The problem is that the JS script catches the response and thus displays my home page in pop up div.

What I need is to detect that the response is successful on login and perform an entire page refresh. I tried to trigger `document.location.reload();` on successful login but again - reload is cached by JS inside the popup div.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most beautiful solution but what about sending a variable in the URL and use that to read if the response is successful?

Comment: hmm, could you provide some example. General, even if pseidocode